# PDF doc view flickers continously

Tags: pdf, docview

I just configured my emacs to display PDFs using doc view. But the problem is that the display flickers continuously. It seems that doc view is constantly refreshing the frame leading to an unpleasant display. How do I stop it from doing this?

Also, I haven't done any customization to doc view in my .emacs yet.

I'm using emacs 24.4 on Windows 8.1 64 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with PDFView and it turned out that the flickering was caused by Blink-Cursor mode. Try to disable this minor mode in the buffer.

Comment: You're right!! I had given up hope thinking it was some dll issue on Windows. Thanks a lot.